# How to show a matrix as a scalar multiple of identity matrix?

Tags: r, math, matrix

**In R programming**, construct a matrix B from given data. Show that BxBxB is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix and find the scalar.

```
data<-c(1,4,-3,2,2,-1,3,6,-3)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Since `data` is 9 elements long, and we are looking for a square matrix, it must be 3 x 3 elements:

```r
data <- c(1,4,-3,2,2,-1,3,6,-3)

B <- matrix(data, nrow = 3) 

B
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]    4    2    6
#> [3,]   -3   -1   -3
```

In R, matrix multiplication is carried out by the operator `%*%`, so we need to do:

```r
B %*% B %*% B
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   -6    0    0
#> [2,]    0   -6    0
#> [3,]    0    0   -6
```

We can see from this that the result is the same as the 3 x 3 identity matrix times -6:

```
identical(B %*% B %*% B, diag(3) * -6)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>